# Which star did Uranus occult in 1977 when the planet's rings were discovered?

Tags: history, planetary-ring, uranus

In 1977, Uranus occulted a star, and the starlight flickered 40 minutes before and after the actual occultation, revealing Uranus' rings.
This is common knowledge to astronomers, but what I can't find out is *which star* Uranus occulted. Can someone give me the name of this star?

Comment: I've just asked [Why was this answer deleted? Is it possible to re-open and this link added to it?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/490/7982)

Answer (score 13):

From wikipedia, the [rings of uranus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rings_of_Uranus)

> The definitive discovery of the Uranian Rings [...] use[d] the occultation of the star SAO 158687[...]

The star [SAO 158687](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-basic?Ident=SAO%20158687&submit=SIMBAD%20search), also cataloged as [HD 128598](http://news.sky-map.org/starview?object_type=1&object_id=1405322&object_name=HD%20128598&locale=SV) is a magnitude 8.7, orange dwarf star in Libra. There seems to be nothing special about the star, except that one day, a planet passed in front of it.

Comment: A planet with previously unknown rings passed in front of it